# initializing c++ classes globally

Tags: c++, class, dlib

I am a beginner in c++ classes and using dlib face detector. In the example code for use with webcam, the face detection and pose model are loaded inside the main function like this:

```
int main(){
    frontal_face_detector detector = get_frontal_face_detector();
    shape_predictor pose_model;
    deserialize("shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat") >> pose_model;
```

}

However, my project is structured in a way that dlib face detection is called through another function instead of main as in the example. Therefore, I need to make the models global so that the function that performs dlib knows what 'detector' and 'pose_model' are without having to pass it in as arguments to that function. Is there anyway to do that? If I load the models inside the function itself then it gets loaded everytime I call the function, thereby reducing performance.

static dlib::frontal_face_detector detector;
 static dlib::shape_predictor pose_model;

Currently I am using 'static' to load them inside the function itself but I am not sure if that is correct C++? Apologies for weird format of the question as this is my first question on this forum. Appreciate the understanding and help!!
Thanks

Comment: static outside the function. If in multiple files, redeclare that variable as "extern". You can also do it in a header included by all other source files. Source: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/42-global-variables/

Comment: Yes, your usage is correct:  static inside a function limits the scope (only the function may see it), there is only one instantiation per program run, and instantiation will occur the first time the function is called.  However, if you have a threaded program, a mutex lock will be required.  If these limitations do not prevent you from following your specifications, then it's fine to use static inside a function.

Comment: Thanks kfmfe04. that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply declare them globally when you initialize them as you would any other global variables.

```
frontal_face_detector detector = get_frontal_face_detector();
shape_predictor pose_model;

int main(){

       deserialize("shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat") >> pose_model;
       ...
}
```